# avoid dropbox choser to open in new window in ios webapp

Tags: web-applications, dropbox, dropbox-api

i'm working on an ios webapp that runs like a standalone and offline-capable app and not in mobile safari. i would like to offer dropbox file upload via the javascript choser dropin. unfortunately the choser opens in a new window and thus breaks the app by jumping into mobile safari and leaving the app window. is it possible to redirect it to open in an iframe or is there a similar solution that avoids having to leave the app window?

any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wrapper like Apache Cordova you can use inAppBrowser.....
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html
this will open a "in your app" safari and you can always come back to your app